# Hide Message after few Sec using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in which i am displaying a message after login.

This is how i do it

```
options.waitingForOperator = 'Custom Message';
```

And then

```
$('#chat-box-msg').html(options.waitingForOperator);
```

Now i was trying to hide only the `message` i.e `(options.waitingForOperator)` after few second.

I read i can use settimeout, but not understanding how do i use iy to hide just the message

```
setTimeout(function () {

}, 3000);
```

I tried a lot but could not succeed.

Can anyone help me, because i am in learning phase of `JQUERY`

**Update**

```
if (chatId === null || chatId === '') {

    if (nametext1 !== '') {
        myHub.server.requestChat(msg);
        $('#chat-box-msg').html(options.waitingForOperator);
    } else {
        alert(");
    }
} else {
    myHub.server.send(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use keywords

e.g options & dot (.) in options.waitingForOperator

try with .hide in setTimeout

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    waitingForOperator ='Custom Message';
    $('#chat-box-msg').html(waitingForOperator);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#chat-box-msg').hide(waitingForOperator);
    }, 3000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5SUm/

Comment: Thanks. But know i cannot afford to change it because then i will have to update too many things based on it :(

Comment: And even if i do above complete div is getting hidden

Comment: @Richa ok so try with directly .... write message in html('Custom Message') and .hide('Custom Message')

Comment: if you don't want to hide your div then ....check this http://jsfiddle.net/s5SUm/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#chat-box-msg').empty();
    }, 3000);
```

After three seconds, the above code will empty the `#chat-box-msg` element.

Comment: If i do above,whole chat box will get empty. And i dont want other things to get hidden except the message :(

Comment: @Richa where r u showing ur message ...would be helful if u post ur html code

Answer (score 0):

you can use empty() which will just clear the inner text or content.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#chat-box-msg').empty();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: But there are other text also which i don;t want to get cleared, so i cannot use that :(

Comment: can you show me your DOM/HTML structure for #chat-box-msg
please click here to see live code http://i.seemikecode.com/cmc?id=m8o9Pmdb7

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to solve it.

```
if (nametext1 !== '') {
               myHub.server.requestChat(msg);
                $('#chat-box-msg').html('<div id=messagediv>' + options.waitingForOperator +'</div>');
                 setTimeout(function () {
                                        $('#messagediv').hide();

                                        }, 3000);

                                }
```

THanks a lot **@Mr7-itsurdeveloper**